# Display:none not showing with display:block at breakpoint

Tags: css, media-queries, breakpoints, show-hide, display

I'm sorry i know it's been asked before but i just can't figure why it doesn't work! 
**I have the meta tag viewport in the head** 
I have a **display:none** icon (bars) at wide viewports (i started from there) and it should appear at smaller size when the menu disappears. (menu disappearing works)
I've set it to **display:block** 
My SCSS:

```
.fa-bars {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    .fa-bars {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

---

But it doesn't work i don't know why
tried to select it with just *i*, with the class, 
 i don't know please send help.

---

Comment: In CSS you can't nest selectors like that. You need some CSS preprocessor like SCSS.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Comment: It might be a css priority issue. Watch for result in chrome inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose both in media queries and correct your css syntax. try this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:601px){
 .fa-bars{
   display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .container .fa-bars{
      display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your media query, this won't work:

```
.container{
            .fa-bars{
                display: block;
            }
        }
```

It should either be:

```
.container .fa-bars {
    display:block;
}
```

... if it's important that the .fa-bars is in .containers.
Otherwise this will be fine:

```
.fa-bars {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `SCSS` for nesting blocks,
trying doing it like this:

```
.fa-bars{
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){

    .container.fa-bars{
            display: block;
    }
```